# Why are operators in the expression new Date().getTime() applied in strict left-to-right order?

Tags: javascript, operators

The following expression seems to work as intended and return the current timestamp.

```
new Date().getTime()
```

However I can't understand why operators are applied in strict left-to-right order here.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operator_precedence) says the member (`.`) operator has higher priority than `new`. This would mean that `.` must be applied before `new`. So the expression should be evaluated as:

```
new (Date().getTime())
```

But in fact it is evaluated as:

```
(new Date()).getTime()
```

I guess there has to be something I've overlooked, but I can't understand what.

*Note*: I don't actually use this expression (I prefer `Date.now()` method). It's just my curiosity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MDN precedence table isn't really correct; the `new` operator and the property access operators are all part of the *MemberExpression* non-terminal in the grammar. Since they're left-associative operators,

```
new something.something
```

is evaluated as

```
(new something).something
```

[Here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2) is the relevant part of the spec.

Therefore in your sample expression

```
new Date().getTime()
```

the whole left side of the `.` is parsed as a *MemberExpression*. What kind of *MemberExpression* is it? It's a `new MemberExpression` production, so that's deeper into the parse tree and that gives us the left-associative behavior.

*edit* — something else I just thought of. Let's say we have an object:

```
var obj = {
  findConstructor: function(name) {
    return window[name];
  }
};
```

Now, let's try that expression to get the time using this object:

```
new obj.findConstructor("Date")().getTime()
```

That'll give you an error. (I'm on thin ice here:) That's because it parses that as

```
new (obj.findConstructor("Date")().getTime)()
```

which clearly won't work.  Instead, you have to add explicit parentheses:

```
(new obj.findConstructor("Date")()).getTime()
```

Comment: The more detailed table that it links to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table - shows the three having the same precedence.

Comment: Indeed it does, which is nice because that's the way it actually works :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I can't trust MDN).

Comment: @hindmost well on the bright side, it's a wiki so if you have the patience you can fix it :) That's cold comfort in a lot of cases, however, and this is a good example: fixing that would require reworking that table, and figuring out exactly how to do that might take a while.

Comment: @hindmost answer updated with stuff that may make your head hurt (it does mine)

Comment: That's very exotic case for me). But anyway thanks, I'll keep it in mind.